# Force element to move up

Tags: html, css

I have a box that is rendering lower and I cant figure out why.

[image]

```
<div id="hint-history" class="popup">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="closehistorypopup">

        <div class="body">

            <button class="x">
                <span class="sprite close"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="title">Hint History</div>

            <div class="lists">
                <?php for($i=0;$i<6;$i++) { ?>
                    <div class="list history[[$i]]" id="history[[$i]]">  
                        <div class="info">
                            <div class="picture monophoto">
                                <div class="text">BO</div>
                                <div class="img" style="background-image: url();"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <div class="lineone">John Smith</div>
                                <div class="linetwo">Daily Essentials</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="boxes">
                            <div class="left">
                                <div class="box box1"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <div class="box box2"></div>
                                <div class="box box3"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="cbutton whiteonblack">VIEW LIST<!--SEE <span class="owner">JOHN'S</span>--></a>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php $i++; $privateCount = 1; ?>
                @if ($privateCount > 0)
                    <div id="privatecard" class="list history[[$i]]">  
                        <div class="info">
                            <div class="picture monophoto" style="visibility: hidden;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <p id="privatecounter">                        
                                    @if ($privateCount == 1)
                                        There is [[$privateCount]] private user.
                                    @else
                                        There are [[$privateCount]] private users.
                                    @endif
                                </p>
                                <div class="linetwo">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="linetwo">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="linetwo">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="boxes">
                            <div class="left">
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
```

No matter what I do it wont budge.

```
.privatecard {
     margin-top: -500px !important;
}
.privatecard {
     padding-bottom: 500px !important;
}

//etc
```

How can I force it to move up?

Comment: Could you please include all relevant CSS for the elements in question? Not just what CSS you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post a fiddle?

I've had this issue in the past though, and I've resolved it by a combination of making sure all `inline-block` elements are also `vertical-align:top;` (or any other state, as long as it's all consistent). AND then, set a `min-height` to the parent container, and a `min-height` to all the `inline-block`'d elements